# Customized UIPickerView , iOS

Tags: button, view, customization, picker

I am trying to make a UIButton for the user where he will be able to choose between 5 different options. I have in mind something like an one line UIButton where one option will be preselected and when the user presses the button the 5 options would be displayed for the user to choose. In the objects library the closest i can find to that is the picker view , but its too big for my screen and it displays all the options , as i only want one to be displayed in the beginning and when the user hits the button all the options so that he can pick a different one if he likes. Is there a UIButton like this on Xcode that i am missing or should i customize a picker view or something? 
Thank you in advance for reading my post :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize picker view like following

http://code4app.net/ios/Customized-Picker-View/4f72e7446803faa901000002

But I suggest that you use custom view which contains custom table view 
and that view is shown as like picker view,means all properties like size,animation,position etc 
all are in your control

If you want to customize table view like that
then follow the link

http://code4app.net/ios/3D-Tableview/4fc0da756803fae46f000000